# How can I use Indy to send messages to multiple email addresses that are stored within a TListView component?

Tags: delphi, indy, indy10, tlistview

I am trying to take a list of emails from within a `TListView` and assign them to `TIdMessage.Recipients.EMailAddresses`. I'm trying to take the ListView captions and assign them as recipient email addresses, however I cannot work out how to do it.

Here is my currently broken code:

```pascal
procedure TfrmEmailer.btnSendClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  smtpServer: TIdSMTP;
  msgEmail: TIdMessage;
  ssl: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
  i: integer;

begin
  smtpServer := TIdSMTP.Create(nil);
  msgEmail := TIdMessage.Create(nil);
  ssl := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(nil);

  ssl.SSLOptions.Method := sslvTLSv1_2;
  ssl.SSLOptions.Mode := sslmUnassigned;
  ssl.SSLOptions.VerifyMode := [];
  ssl.SSLOptions.VerifyDepth := 0;

  msgEmail.Sender.Address := edtSenderAddress.Text;
  msgEmail.Sender.Name := edtSenderName.Text;
  msgEmail.ReplyTo.EMailAddresses := edtReplyTo.Text;
  for i := 0 to length(lsvRecipients.ItemIndex) do
  begin
    msgEmail.Recipients.EMailAddresses := lsvRecipients.Items[0].Caption;
  end;

  msgEmail.Subject := edtSubject.Text;
  msgEmail.Body.Text := redBody.Text;

  smtpServer.IOHandler := ssl;
  smtpServer.Host := edtHost.Text;
  smtpServer.Port := StrToInt(edtPort.Text);
  smtpServer.Username := edtUsername.Text;
  smtpServer.Password := edtPassword.Text;
  smtpServer.UseTLS := utUseExplicitTLS;

  smtpServer.Connect;
  smtpServer.Send(msgEmail);
  smtpServer.Disconnect;

  smtpServer.Free;
  msgEmail.Free;
  ssl.Free;

  // Output
  beep;
  ShowMessage('Email Sent!');
end;

procedure TfrmEmailer.btnAddEmailClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  emailToAdd := lsvRecipients.Items.Add;
  emailToAdd.Caption := edtAddEmail.Text;
end;
```

Comment: `for i := 0 to length(lsvRecipients.ItemIndex) do` should probably be `for i := 0 to lsvRecipients.Items.Count - 1 do` and `msgEmail.Recipients.EMailAddresses` is clearly wrong since it keeps overwriting the same property. Also, `lsvRecipients.Items[0].Caption` should clearly be `lsvRecipients.Items[i].Caption`. And you need to use `try..finally` blocks to protect your resources.

Comment: Thanks Andreas. I didn't realise it was possible to put a variable as the Items index but that makes sense. 

What is a resource?

Answer (score 3):

`TIdMessage.Recipients.EMailAddresses` is designed as a single delimited string containing multiple email addresses, but you are assigning individual email addresses to it over and over in a loop, so it is going to contain only the last email address that you assign.

In this situation, use `TIdMessage.Recipients.Add()` instead of `TIdMessage.Recipients.EMailAddresses`.

Also, you are not enumerating the `TListView` items correctly.  And you are not protecting your code from leaking memory if exceptions are raised.

Try this instead:

```pascal
var
  smtpServer: TIdSMTP;
  msgEmail: TIdMessage;
  ssl: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
  i: integer;
begin
  smtpServer := TIdSMTP.Create(nil);
  try
    msgEmail := TIdMessage.Create(smtpServer);

    msgEmail.Sender.Address := edtSenderAddress.Text;
    msgEmail.Sender.Name := edtSenderName.Text;
    msgEmail.ReplyTo.EMailAddresses := edtReplyTo.Text;

    for i := 0 to lsvRecipients.Count-1 do
    begin
      msgEmail.Recipients.Add.Address := lsvRecipients.Items[i].Caption;
      // or:
      // msgEmail.Recipients.Add.Text := lsvRecipients.Items[i].Caption;
    end;

    msgEmail.Subject := edtSubject.Text;
    msgEmail.Body.Text := redBody.Text;

    ssl := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(smtpServer);
    ssl.SSLOptions.Method := sslvTLSv1_2;
    ssl.SSLOptions.Mode := sslmUnassigned;
    ssl.SSLOptions.VerifyMode := [];
    ssl.SSLOptions.VerifyDepth := 0;

    smtpServer.IOHandler := ssl;
    smtpServer.Host := edtHost.Text;
    smtpServer.Port := StrToInt(edtPort.Text);
    smtpServer.Username := edtUsername.Text;
    smtpServer.Password := edtPassword.Text;
    smtpServer.UseTLS := utUseExplicitTLS;

    smtpServer.Connect;
    try
      smtpServer.Send(msgEmail);
    finally
      smtpServer.Disconnect;
    end;
  finally
    smtpServer.Free;
  end;

  // Output
  Beep;
  ShowMessage('Email Sent!');
end;

procedure TfrmEmailBomber.btnAddEmailClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  emailToAdd: TListItem;
begin
  emailToAdd := lsvRecipients.Items.Add;
  emailToAdd.Caption := edtAddEmail.Text;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I don't understand why the count has to have -1 at the end. If I omit it, I get a memory access violation. Is it because it is trying to search for an email in a place where there is not one?

`for i := 0 to lsvRecipients.Count-1 do`

Comment: @Bollywagger "*I don't understand why the count has to have -1 at the end*" - read Delphi's documentation: [For Statements](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Declarations_and_Statements_(Delphi)#For_Statements). "*is it because it is trying to search for an email in a place where there is not one?*" - yes, without the -1, the loop will go out of bounds of the `Items` collection.

Comment: @Bollywagger: The reason that the -1 is needed is that the list starts at index 0. For example, if there are 10 items in the listview, `Count` will be 10, but the valid indexes are 0  through 9.

Comment: @KenWhite Funnily enough, I've been getting back into Delphi, going over all the basics again, and I read about this exact thing today.